# Check if there is a condition in each row in python and assing to a new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, variables

I have a dataframe `unir` in Python and I want to check if there is a certain text pattern in an URL. If the pattern is present, I want to assign a value to a new variable, if it doesn't, I want to leave the variable blank.

A sample of my data is the following:

```
sample =[
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/ley-de-factura-electronica.html",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoempleo/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/examen-acceso-abogacia.html",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/informe-pisa/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/dificultades-de-aprendizaje.html",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/informe-pisa/profesores-salarios.html",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoempleo/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/evento/ii-festival-de-teatro-unir/",
"https://en.unir.net/revista/noticias/page/64/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoempleo/",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/informe-pisa/profesores-salarios.html",
"https://www.unir.net/revista/"]

unir = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns=["url"])
```

And I'm searchig for the pattern "https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales" doing the following:

```
for x in unir["url"]:
    if (unir["url"].str.contains("https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales")) is True:
        unir["arees"] = "Especiales"
    else:
        unir["arees"] = ""
```

But it only returns blanks.

I don't know what seems to be the problem...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid loops, because slow, better is use vectorized solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = unir["url"].str.contains("https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales")
unir["arees"] = np.where(mask, "Especiales", '')
print (unir)
                                                  url       arees
0   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/ley-de...  Especiales
1   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoem...  Especiales
2                       https://www.unir.net/revista/            
3   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/examen...  Especiales
4   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/inform...  Especiales
5                       https://www.unir.net/revista/            
6   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/dificu...  Especiales
7   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/inform...  Especiales
8   https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoem...  Especiales
9   https://www.unir.net/revista/evento/ii-festiva...            
10      https://en.unir.net/revista/noticias/page/64/            
11  https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/autoem...  Especiales
12  https://www.unir.net/revista/especiales/inform...  Especiales
13                      https://www.unir.net/revista/
```

Comment: Thanks! I just only want to add that i needed to load the numpy library before running the script:

Comment: use `import numpy as np` ;)

Comment: and if install pandas, numpy is required package, so also installed with pandas